Join columns with HasMany in Laravel
I have 3 tables - users, products and user_products. I try get user_products for user with products data. I can get user_products by $this->hasMany(ProductUser::class) but how can I get products atributes (title and other) from Product table in one query? Or I have to do query for every product? I'm new in Laravel, tnx.

You can do it with hasManyThrough. See more details here https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

That sounds like a many-to-many relationship between users and products to me. I suggest set up a BelongsToMany relationship between theses two:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class User extends Model
{
    public function products(): BelongsToMany
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}

And you can always retrieve data from the pivot table, in this scenario, that user_products table.

In User Modal -> User.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'user_products');
}

In Product Modal -> Product.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_products');
}

In your controller -> Eger load the product with user
public function showUserProducts($userId)
{
    $user = User::with('products')->find($userId);
    if (!$user) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User not found');
    }
    return view('user.products', compact('user'));
}

In your blade file to show data -> user/ products.blade.php
@foreach ($user->products as $product) 
    <h1>{{ $product->title }}</h1>
@endforeach

